# Detecting Versions of IE Earlier Than 8

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have this code in my HTML:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script language="javascript">
alert("This page does not display properly in versions of Internet Explorer earlier than 8.\nPlease upgrade to IE8 (or later).");
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

However, the alert is triggered even when the page is accessed with IE8 whether IE8 is in Compatibility View or not.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Comp View (Quirksmode) is not enough to test IE stuff. You need the IE F12 (Developer) Tools - they should be included by default. There, you can pick what version of IE to use (Browser Mode) for your page. It has always worked for me. Of course, it is not 100% accurate, but its the closest you will get to an actual copy of the previous versions of IE

Answer (score 0):

You can put some version-specific styles in your CSS then detect them using JavaScript.

```
.test {
  margin-left: 8px;  --> for all browsers
  _margin-left: 6px; --> for ie6
  #margin-left: 7px; --> for ie7 and below
}
```

Query out the value of margin-left and you can then detect IE7 and 6 easily.